# Entry node requested site anonymity

Tags: anonymity

Does an entry node see a requested site or tor (*.onion*) site?
Or does it only know the IP address and nothing else?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry node knows nothing but your IP and the ID of the next node in your chosen circuit. The rest of the node IDs and the request payload are encrypted such that they can't be read by anyone but the intended nodes.